# Worksheets().Range().Formula doesn't work in an Excel vba function?

Tags: excel, vba, function, formula

I have a problem by using "Worksheets().Range().Formula" with Excel VBA.
If I use a macro, it works fine (See Sub Method below).
But if I use it in a function it doesn't work and I have an "#VALEUR!" (in French, I think it would be #VALUE! in English) error message in the CELL.
How to solve the problem ?
I'm using EXCEL 2010

```
Sub StoreFormula()
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D20").Formula = "='Sheet2'!D13"
End Sub

Function Test() As String 
   Call StoreFormula
   Test = Application.Caller.Address
End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User Defined Worksheet functions called from a cell formula can only return a value to the calling cell(s): they cannot change a formula or value in any other cell.